# Symlink launcher icon not visible on Unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I have created a symlink launcher icon on my desktop to open a program. When I set the icon for the symlink launcher it appears on the Desktop but when I drag it onto the Unity launcher the icon changes to the default spring icon.

How do I get the icon to show in the Unity launcher?

The icon I am using is a 24px x 24px PNG, does it need to be 256px x 256px instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a .desktop file for it and place it in `~/.local/share/applications/`. In the desktop file, specify an icon and quicklists if you want to. You'll then find it in the dash and you can drag it to the launcher.